# Which typescript type do I have to use when I want to call a function with file buffer?

Tags: node.js, typescript, fs

I want read an image in filebuffer, change this in a function and than write back.

In Javascript:

```
const changeImage = ( buf) => {
     ... change buf

    return buf
}

let imageFileBuffer = fs.readFileSync('./in.png');
let newBuf = changeImage(imageFileBuffer)
fs.writeFileSync('out.png', newBuf);
```

How do i convert this to typescript? What is the type of buf?

Comment: Look at the return type of [`readFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) when you don't pass it an encoding.

Comment: I will join my previous speaker and add the link to the documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options

You will see, the return value is a `Buffer`: https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html

Comment: Your ref go to javascript doc, but this is typescript? I'm new in typescript! If I understand right, I must look in the right *.d.ts file in node_modules!? But where is this?

Answer (score 0):

If you run `npm install -D @types/node`, you will have node types available. After doing this, reload your window (close VS Code, or do CTRL + SHIFT + P and select reload [CMD + SHIFT + P on mac]).

Now hover over your `imageFileBuffer` variable to see what type it is (should just be Buffer). Then add the type to your variable to get the intellisense to do the import of the type.

**EDIT**

I just checked one of my projects and there is nothing to import after installing the types package. They are defined as global.

Comment: It may work on VS Code. But I work on Intellij and want understand more the background not only type the right shortcut!

Comment: it's the same premise-- install the types package and ensure your environment is using them. I use type inference all the time to see what the type should be (usually in languages that have method overloading).